# non-atomic operations on atomic variables and vice versa

Tags: c++, c, atomic

Given the below code:

```
static int x;

static void f() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    atomic_fetch_add(&x, 3);
}
```

Further, assume that `f` is called by two threads concurrently. Does C/C++ memory model guarantee that the result would always be `600` on all hardware platforms?

And what if I changed it to the below? Is the result still guaranteed to be `600` on all hardware platforms?

```
static atomic_int a_x;

static void f() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    a_x += 3;
}
```

Or the result is not guaranteed and I should never mix atomic operations with non-atomic types and vice versa?

PS: I used an int type here but my question applies to any type `T` and `_Atomic T`.

Comment: What is specifically unclear from the [`atomic_fetch_add()` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/atomic_fetch_add) for you?

Comment: This is easier to answer if you choose between C and C++

Comment: It doesn't say anything about mixing atomic variables with non-atomic operations and vice versa. And gcc compiles both without any warning.

Comment: tl;dr: pointers to atomic and non-atomic types are not compatible with each other, so passing `&x` to `atomic_fetch_add` is not valid.

Comment: (The second snippet *is* guaranteed to result in `a_x == 100`. [Built-in increment and decrement operators and compound assignment are read-modify-write atomic operations with total sequentially consistent ordering](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/atomic); i.e. `a_x += 3` *is* an atomic operation.)

Comment: @trentcl: did you mean `a_x=600`?

Comment: Yes... yes, I did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use atomic operations on non-atomic variables, you can use [std::atomic_ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_ref) (C++20). You can see an example [here](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/atomic-ref).

Your second example should be fine because `a_x` is atomic with `memory_order_seq_cst` memory model and `+=` is [defined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_arith2) for it as an atomic operation.

Comment: Same is true of the += operator in C: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_assignment. Thanks!

Comment: @user3124390: It's at 6.5.16.2 (3) in the C17 standard.  Incidentally, there is a (non-normative) note 7.17.7.5(5) which contradicts this and says they are not  guaranteed atomic, but this seems to be an error and is mentioned in [Defect Report 486](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm#dr_486).