# Using std::atomic with futex system call

Tags: c++, linux, c++20, stdatomic, futex

In C++20, we got the capability to sleep on atomic variables, waiting for their value to change.
We do so by using the [`std::atomic::wait`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/wait) method.

Unfortunately, while `wait` has been standardized, `wait_for` and `wait_until` are not. Meaning that we cannot sleep on an atomic variable with a timeout.

Sleeping on an atomic variable is anyway implemented behind the scenes with [WaitOnAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitonaddress) on Windows and the [futex](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/futex.2.html) system call on Linux.

Working around the above problem (no way to sleep on an atomic variable with a timeout), I could pass the memory address of an `std::atomic` to `WaitOnAddress` on Windows and it will (kinda) work with no UB, as the function gets `void*` as a parameter, and it's valid to cast `std::atomic<type>` to `void*`

On Linux, it is unclear whether it's ok to mix `std::atomic` with `futex`.  `futex` gets either a `uint32_t*` or a `int32_t*` (depending which manual you read), and casting `std::atomic<u/int>` to `u/int*` is UB. On the other hand, the manual says

> The uaddr argument points to the futex word.  ***On all platforms,
> futexes are four-byte integers that must be aligned on a four-
> byte boundary***.  The operation to perform on the futex is
> specified in the futex_op argument; val is a value whose meaning
> and purpose depends on futex_op.

Hinting that `alignas(4) std::atomic<int>` should work, and it doesn't matter which integer type is it is as long as the type has the size of 4 bytes and the alignment of 4.

Also, I have seen many places where this trick of combining atomics and futexes is implemented, including [boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/boost/fiber/detail/futex.hpp) and [TBB](https://github.com/wjakob/tbb/blob/141b0e310e1fb552bdca887542c9c1a8544d6503/src/tbb/semaphore.h#L205).

So what is the best way to sleep on an atomic variable with a timeout in a non UB way?
Do we have to implement our own atomic class with OS primitives to achieve it correctly?

(Solutions like mixing atomics and condition variables exist, but sub-optimal)

Comment: `WaitOnAddress` is a limited implementation of a condition variable, atomicity is irrelevant. So instead of using atomics, why don't you try the classic condition variable from the standard library?

Comment: @facetus throughput, mainly.

Comment: `WaitOnAddress` has nothing to do with atomics and I am pretty sure won't give you any benefits compared to `std::condition_variable`. `WaitOnAddress` IS a condition variable by its semantic, it just hides the explicit mutex behind the scene. Besides that it does exactly the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't necessarily have to implement a full custom `atomic` API, it should actually be safe to simply pull out a pointer to the underlying data from the `atomic<T>` and pass it to the system.

Since `std::atomic` does not offer some equivalent of `native_handle` like other synchronization primitives offer, you're going to be stuck doing some implementation-specific hacks to try to get it to interface with the native API.

For the most part, it's reasonably safe to assume that first member of these types in implementations will be the same as the `T` type -- at least for integral values <sup>[1]</sup>. This is an assurance that will make it possible to extract out this value.

> ... and casting `std::atomic<u/int>` to `u/int*` is UB

This isn't actually the case.

[`std::atomic`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) is guaranteed by the standard to be [Standard-Layout Type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_standard_layout). One helpful but often esoteric properties of standard layout types is that it is safe to `reinterpret_cast` a [`T` to a value or reference of the **first sub-object**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30618045/1678770) (e.g. the first member of the `std::atomic`).

As long as we can guarantee that the `std::atomic<u/int>` contains *only* the `u/int` as a member (or at least, as its first member), then it's completely safe to extract out the type in this manner:

```cpp
auto* r = reinterpret_cast<std::uint32_t*>(&atomic);
// Pass to futex API...
```

This approach should also hold on windows to cast the `atomic` to the underlying type before passing it to the `void*` API.

**Note:** Passing a `T*` pointer to a `void*` that gets reinterpreted as a `U*` (such as an `atomic<T>*` to `void*` when it expects a `T*`) is *undefined behavior* -- even with standard-layout guarantees (as far as I'm aware). It will still *likely work* because the compiler can't see into the system APIs -- but that doesn't make the code well-formed.

**Note 2:** I can't speak on the `WaitOnAddress` API as I haven't actually used this -- but any atomics API that depends on the address of a properly aligned integral value (`void*` or otherwise) should work properly by extracting out a pointer to the underlying value.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Since this is tagged `C++20`, you can verify this with [`std::is_layout_compatible`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_layout_compatible) with a `static_assert`:

```cpp
static_assert(std::is_layout_compatible_v<int,std::atomic<int>>);
```

(Thanks to @apmccartney for this suggestion in the comments).

I can confirm that this will be layout compatible for [Microsoft's STL](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/ccc5aaaadc6dd1a1f80fb4d0755aff468817a274/stl/inc/atomic#L401), [libc++](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/78d6a7767ed57b50122a161b91f59f19c9bd0d19/include/atomic#L923), and [libstdc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/88202c883c07da1c03dbb1ad440f1b70189c4399/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/atomic#L209); however if you don't have access to `is_layout_compatible` and you're using a different system, you might want to check your compiler's headers to ensure this assumption holds.

Comment: Interesting point about UB.  It would be UB to *deref* an `int*` to an `atomic<int>` object without synchronization to make sure no other threads were reading/writing it at the time, but passing it to `futex` is basically like using an `atomic_ref<int>` operation on that int object - you're invoking machine code that's designed to be safe in the presence of other threads simultaneously reading+writing.  As long as the `atomic<T>` is lock-free; maybe a static_assert on `is_always_lock_free` would be a good idea if you're also doing belt-and-suspenders stuff like `alignas(4) std::atomic<int>`.

Comment: I was thinking about suggesting the `static_assert` on `is_always_lock_free` -- but decided against it. Extending `atomic` in this way will pretty much always require _some_ level of coupling with the `std::atomic` implementation -- and at which point there will likely have to be some knowledge of the implementation to really share this between the native system APIs. Also to the "_UB to deref an `int*`_ ..." point -- _technically_ it wouldn't be UB since the pointer is legal and valid. It just wouldn't be _sequenced_ if it was accessed in a threaded context (which would make it UB)

Comment: That's exactly what I meant by "without synchronization...": you could create data-race UB, not strict-aliasing UB.

Comment: Re: Footnote [1]

This can be verified programmatically. See std::is_layout_compatible.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_layout_compatible

Comment: @apmccartney Excellent suggestion! I haven't fully explored all the new traits added in C++20, so thank you for bringing that to my attention

Comment: `static_assert(sizeof(int) == sizeof(std::atomic<int>) && std::atomic<int>::is_always_lock_free)` is a reasonable best-effort check with C++17 but without C++20.  If they're the same size and atomic_int is lock_free, that rules out most possible incompatibility.

Comment: According to GCC 12 (which apparently is the only compiler implementing this by now), it's not compatible: https://godbolt.org/z/1hvn1qa3T
Then again, `sizeof()` and `alignof()` are equal and I'm not sure what exactly GCC is testing.

Comment: Welp, this works: https://godbolt.org/z/ze4Wqrrn7
I guess, https://wg21.link/P0466R5 states "Two types cv1 T1 and cv2 T2 are layout-compatible types if T1 and T2 are the same type,
layout-compatible enumerations, or layout-compatible standard-layout class types." and `int` is not a "standard-layout class type". Nothing seems to be stated about primitive types.

Comment: @WolleTD Interesting observation on the layout compatibility! If that's the case, then it's possible the `is_layout_compatible_v` part of the suggestion is moot; but that shouldn't change the fact that `reinterpret_cast`ing to the first member of a standard-layout object is a legal operation

Comment: @Human-Compiler that's exactly what I would argue.
The layout-compatibility is defined in the standard here: http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types.general#11
The `reinterpret_cast` bit is valid because of this: http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#general-27

"Layout" in C++ appears to include the types of the members, not just size and alignment: http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#general-23.
But even with that, I'd say that a standard-layout class with a single member could be layout-compatible with that single member. It's just not defined.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a "non-atomic" `alignas(4) uint32_t` variable with the futex calls, and perform other atomic operations on them via `std::atomic_ref`.  See [non-atomic operations on atomic variables and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66066605/non-atomic-operations-on-atomic-variables-and-vice-versa)